# GUI Maker? Is there a perhaps drag and drop GUI maker for Mma?

Tags: gui-construction

IDE's like Borland, Eclipse, and others have ways of making GUI's. Drag and drop is usually the way of it. Then one puts the variables together and links up everything. Mma seems to handle (at least so far) in the GUI development department like Machine language. One had to develop ones own libraries of codes to paste into the existing. Is there a more graphical way of designing GUI's in Mma? Know of anyone working on this?      A thought here is the Mma Options menu and many others.  Someone wrote all of that code by hand. Seems like a good job for a computer. Drag and drop. Drag a button onto the "screen" and give it a variable name. Drag an Text input field onto the screen and give it a variable name. Drag a DB handler onto the screen (not front end) and link it up.

Or  perhaps a separate question

Linking an Eclipse generated Java Front end, that is GUI to Mma.   Probably a JLink question?

Comment: To my knowledge there isn't.

Comment: There was some talk about having one when they bought math modelica. Maybe in V10??

Comment: Yes, create your own, using Java Swing, JavaFX, or WinForms, and then use JLink or NETLink. There are plenty of professional GUI builders out there. Note that JavaFX is the official replacement of Swing, so unless you have a deep background in Swing and have to learn one from scratch, learn JavaFX and ditch Swing.

Comment: You can also use .Netlink and build a GUI (Windows-only) using Microsoft Visual Studio. I am aware of a project that does this.